# how i can take screenshot of specific Other software window in java?

Tags: java, windows, window, screenshot, capture

i just try to take screenshot of a specific software every amount of time i found a way to take screenshot for active window but i need to take it for specific windows altough is not active .

thanks in advance

i tried this but as i told  is take full screenshot:

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\tessdata\\Full_Image.png"));
```

Comment: Plese provide screenshots

Comment: Check out [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/). It doesn't take pixels from the screen. Instead is paints a component to an image.